# Susy and Breakpoint in Gulp-compass: Error: Cannot load such file --susy

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-compass

I encountered an issue when I try to use Susy and Breakpoint to my Gulp-compass. Is there anything I've missed in this code?

```
var compass = require('gulp-compass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
        gulp.task('compass', function(){
            gulp.src('scss/style.scss')
                .pipe(compass({
                    config_file: './config.rb',
                    css: 'css',
                    sass: 'scss',
                    require: ['susy', 'breakpoint']
                }))
                .pipe(autoprefixer({
                    browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
                    cascade: false
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
        });
```

Error Message:

```
 bash-4.3$ gulp
[22:43:43] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Code Demo\Templates\angular\gulpfile.js
[22:43:43] Starting 'scripts'...
[22:43:43] Finished 'scripts' after 9.72 ms
[22:43:43] Starting 'compass'...
[22:43:43] Finished 'compass' after 3.09 ms
[22:43:43] Starting 'default'...
[22:43:43] Finished 'default' after 2.88 μs
[22:43:47] LoadError on line ["54"] of C: cannot load such file -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace


events.js:141
      throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error: Compass failed
```

Comment: I've edited your post to replace your screencap of the error message with the actual text. Next time, please copy and paste your console output the same way you did with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described here: "cannot load such file -- susy".

Try to run this command:

> gem install susy

It helped for me ;-)